# Xamarin Forms - Serialization/Deserialization not working

Tags: serialization, .net-core, xamarin.forms, json.net, .net-standard-2.0

**Expected Behavior:**

In the Xamarin.Forms project (`MyApp`) I am referencing a class library with custom models(`Custom.Netcore.Models.dll`), contained in a separate project/separate solution. The goal is to serialize the models to json from xml files for our API/Database, retrieve and deserialize them via MyApp's REST using Newtonsoft.Json to fill ViewModel objects, create changes through various interactions via MyApp's UI then serialize them and POST to Custom.Netcore.API.

**Actual Behavior:**

The expected behavior only functions when running MyApp via UWP. When trying to run the solution via Android/iOS (Emulators) and the application gets to the REST calls to fill MyApp's ViewModels, the Application successfully GETs the serialized data via

`var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

then when the application attempts to parse the data and deserialize it to the model via

`ObservableCollection<Model> Records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Model>>(data);`

both Android/iOS at this point give the same error and cause the application to stop running:

*Android:*

`System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 0100000c from typeref (expected class 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute' in assembly 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')'`

*iOS:*

`Failed to resolve "System.Void System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute::.ctor()" reference from "System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"`

however, I am able to successfully create and fill ViewModel objects defined with Custom.Netcore.Models.Model on all platforms via something simple like

```
ObservableCollection<Model> Records = new ObservableCollection<Model>()
{
    new Model(){ Id = 0, Description = "First Model", Type = "One"},
    new Model(){ Id = 1, Description = "Second Model", Type = "Two"}
};
```

**Logs:** (Android)

`Can't find custom attr constructor image: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.MyApp/files/.__override__/Custom.Netcore.Models.dll mtoken: 0x0a000010 due to: Could not resolve type with token 0100000c from typeref (expected class 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute' in assembly 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') assembly:System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type:System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute member:(null) **System.TypeLoadException:** 'Could not resolve type with token 0100000c from typeref (expected class 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute' in assembly 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')'`

**Setup:**

*Custom.Netcore.Api:*

- `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>`
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App - v2.1.1
- Microsoft.NETCore.App - v2.1.0
- NETStandard.Library - v.2.0.3
- System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager - v5.0.0-preview.4.20251.6
- System.Data.SqlClient - v4.8.1
- System.Runtime - v4.3.1

*XF.MyApp:*

- `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`
- Xamarin.Forms - v4.7.0.968
- Newtonsoft.Json - v12.0.3
- NETStandard.Library - v2.0.3

*Custom.Netcore.Models.Model.cs:*

```
namespace Custom.Netcore.Models
{
    [Serializable()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Model")]
    public class Model
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**API Data:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "description": "First Model",
    "type" = "One"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Second Model",
    "type" = "Two"
  }
]
```

Been stuck trying to workaround this issue for a week so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why not just use json?  why mix xml and json?

Comment: @Jason thats just how the backend is setup to convert a specific filetype, however everything between API/XF are all json format (I'll edit that part so it's clearer)

Comment: @Jason the xml files are just used to get data into the Database/API, everything else is json when the application is communicating with the api

Comment: This is possibly a linker issue, where the XML libraries are being removed because they are not being statically referenced.  There are a couple of possible workarounds, see the Xamarin linker docs

Comment: @Jason yeah when I right click MyApp.Android and go to Android Options, Ive tried changing Linking -> None to prevent the removals and tried building in both debug/release mode but got the same error.  Do you think it may be the serialization setup inside the model's class or maybe since Im referencing a separate solution/project it isnt reading correctly since the logs on Android are returning:                                                    ```System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute member:(null) ```

Comment: Not sure.  You might try searching/creating an issue on the Newtonsoft github

Comment: Gotcha appreciate your time and help @Jason

Comment: What happens on the emulators if you do `typeof(Model).GetCustomAttributes(true)` ?

Comment: @dbc I still get the same error :/  ```System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 0100000c from typeref (expected class 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute' in assembly 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')'
' in assembly 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')```

Comment: @dbc ```Can't find custom attr constructor image: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.MyApp/files/.__override__/Custom.Netcore.Models.dll mtoken: 0x0a00000b due to: Could not resolve type with token 0100000c from typeref (expected class 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute' in assembly 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') assembly:System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type:System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute member:(null)``` without setting your line to a var

Comment: So that's why Newtonsoft is throwing: a basic reflection method isn't working correctly on the emulators.  Sometime during serialization Newtonsoft tries to get all the custom attributes for `Model`, which fails and throws the exception shown -- despite the fact that the specific attribute is for XML serialization.  Apparently the DLL containing the definition for `XmlRootAttribute` didn't get linked in, or it was removed because it was deemed to be unused.  I'm not an android developer so I can't tell you how to fix that though.

Comment: @dbc sounds similar to what I was reading but that explanation has given me a lot more clarity on why the issue is occuring so thank you very much! Next step is to try it on a real device and hope its just the emulators

Comment: Does it work in a real device?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Updating software to fix compatibility issues and will let you know, still unable to find a similar issue online so assuming it's emulators or linking like @Jason/@dbc suggested

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Got an error deploying to an Android device so it was never able to get to that point, will figure out firmware issues so I can upgrade XCode and try to deploy to an iPhone

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT was unable to get it running on either device, moved the models project over to the same solution and told me something along the lines of MonoAndroid 9.0 is not compatible with netcore 2.1 so Im assuming the incompatibility between the two is whats causing a bad reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs and errorlist wont directly tell you on iOS and Android, and since I couldnt find a similar issue online I'll leave this for someone in the future. If you are using Xamarin Forms and referencing a Class Library Project in a separate solution be aware that if you get a bad reflection or errors similar to those above, the cause of the issue may be incompatibility between MonoAndroid 9 and NetCore 2.1. The fix for this issue in my case was to use the separate solution NetCore 2.1 version for DB tasks and within the same XF solution, add the same Class Library Project then convert it to target the same NetStandard framework since that's what Xamarin Forms is intended to target.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
namespace Custom.Netcore.Models
{
    [Serializable()]
    [JsonProperty("Model")]
    public class Model
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Edit:

or try to use:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode<>
JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode<>
```

insted of:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>
```

Comment: [JsonProperty("name")] in the DB/API didnt change anything for me then tried deserializing with xmlnode/xnode and still got the same error

Comment: First try to parse as JSON to object and then try to parse from object to your XML. When it will work try to optimize. In my opinion, your mistake comes from trying to parse wrong formats.

Comment: If the format is wrong wouldnt it also fail when running UWP and not just Android/iOS? On Android/iOS Im still able to ```JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<object>>(data);``` or one that works better for iterating to fill the collection use ```<Dictionary<string, string>>```on Android/iOS emulator and iterate through that to fill the collection. is there something that looks wrong with my "API Data" example in my post?